# How do I edit the npm config file?

Tags: npm, vue.js, git-bash

I've got a problem with preventing npm live-server from opening the default browser on startup. The solution I've found says I edit `bs-config.js` from my project to prevent this behaviour. The problem is that I don't have a project and I'm simply running my vue-js files (no project, no files except app.js, index.html, styles.css).

So how can I edit npm behaviour globally?

I'm running live-server from git-bash.

Comment: are you using webpack?

Comment: This one? https://github.com/tapio/live-server

Comment: I'm not really sure :) I just installed npm, and typed live-server

Comment: @ArnoldGandarillas I typed live-server -v, so I tells me I'm using live-server 1.2.0, so yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running it from the command line, just include the following flag:

```
live-server --no-browser
```

Also, looking at the source, .live-server.json  should be a json file and not a javascript module:

{

```
  port: 8181, // Set the server port. Defaults to 8080.
  host: "0.0.0.0", // Set the address to bind to. Defaults to 0.0.0.0 or process.env.IP.
  open: false, // When false, it won't load your browser by default.
  logLevel: 2, // 0 = errors only, 1 = some, 2 = lots
}
```

Comment: thank you, --no-browser command works, but json file for some reason does not, but I think that is my fault and your both answers are correct

Answer (score 2):

In your project directory when you type `live-server` pass additional switch `--no-browser` to it

E.g

```
live-server --no-browser
```

For more details read documentation of project given [here](https://github.com/tapio/live-server)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
~/.live-server.json

{
  port: 8181, // Set the server port. Defaults to 8080.
  host: "0.0.0.0", // Set the address to bind to. Defaults to 0.0.0.0 or process.env.IP.
  open: false, // When false, it won't load your browser by default.
  logLevel: 2, // 0 = errors only, 1 = some, 2 = lots
}
```

Check [this](https://github.com/tapio/live-server#usage-from-node) to see more config params.

Comment: it should work, but I need to figure it out. It seems that my live-server ignores this file at startup <?>. I'm on the right folder, I edit this file, but changes aren't affect live-server

Comment: The name of the file needs to be `.live-server.json` pay attention to the dot at the beginning of the name.

Comment: Thank you Arnold, I've got the correct file name, but my live-server command ignores it, not only browser setting, but also the port number. I'm missing something